# About using variable inside of nested if

Tags: c#

```
if(){
      String var=1; 
      if(var==-1){
        //do this
      }
      else
      {
         if()
         {        
           String myString=var; //This is where I want to use var
         }
      }
}
```

Now myString is not getting assigned the value of var..why is that ? It's nested if..it should get the value..isn't it ?

Comment: The fact that you're writing pseudo-code makes it impossible to answer this question. For example, you can't assign the value `1` to a string variable directly. Please give a short but *complete* example.

Comment: @Happy Soul: What .net version you are using?

Comment: You might want to reconsider your chosen brace indent style. Most people would likely find that style hard to read.

Comment: What are the if conditions being evaluated? are they evaluating to true?

Comment: All I wanna know is that nested if's can use parent's if's variables or not..thnx

Comment: And I remember that in C#, var is a reserved already. How can you specify a variable with the name "var"

Comment: Plus, you can't just have an if() without a boolean expression.

Comment: oh wo..sry..I thot I indented it correctly so it's easier to read..how else do u do it if not this way ? :/

Comment: @Tim..It's not complete code :/

Comment: @Happy then back to my original question, is the assignment even getting hit? do you have a breakpoint on the assignment line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following code seems to work fine:

```
if (true)
{
    String var = "1";
    if (var == "-1") {/*DoSomething()*/ }
    else
    {
        if (true)
        {
            String myString = var; //Gives 1 in myString!
            MessageBox.Show(myString);
        }
    }
}
```

[Variable and Method Scope in Microsoft .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx) is a good reference to understand how scoping
works.

Btw, [`var`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx) is a type used in 3.5 and above; should avoid naming variables akin to type names.

Comment: Can you have `var var = "";`?

Comment: @PostMan Yes sir (c# 4.0 VS 2010). Actually doing that would be insanity in almost any case.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is vague and.. unhelpful, but perhaps you should just remember:

```
int n;
if (true) {
  // you can access/change n from here no problem
  int f;
} else {
  // can't access f here, if that answers your question
}
//you cannot access f, it no longer exists.
```

To put it bluntly, anything outside the { } that a variable was declared, would not know about it (even without a condition/loop). *Anything* inside will.

Comment: @Happy same thing goes for nested if statements; variable scope is hierarchal from the top down.

Comment: but could you access "f" from an else statement attached to that if?  I believe that is what the OP is getting at...

Comment: @Adkins - that may be the question, but that doesn't match the code sample (unless someone edits it).  In that case, no, the variable is out of scope.

Answer (score 1):

disregarding all syntax mistakes,
assuming whatever is in the bottom "if" evaluates to "true", and that var is not equal to -1 (you really should put a **breakpoint** there, and see if the debugger ever reaches that assignment). myString will get var's value. Notice however, that **once out of the block** (just after the next "}") myString doest not longer exists.
Also notice all syntax mistakes (using "var" which is a keyword, assigning an int to string...)

Comment: Ididn't bother abt syntax n stuff while asking here..just wanted to know if I can use that variable inside of a nested if..anyway..thnx

Comment: @Happy: As you can see, that made your question rather confusing.. Tried to answer it anyhow, but please do notice that next time.

Answer (score 1):

myString must get the value of var. if not, check your if conditions.

Answer (score 1):

In general, when you declare a variable, its accessible in the scop which is defined in...
In your example, `var` (u cant use this name because this is a reserved word in VS2008) is accesible in all other `if` blocks couse those are in that scop.

Answer (score 1):

Take care of keywords in C# language (and other) :)

Comment: I understand that I need to :)  it's just that I was in a hurry to know if the variable would work inside of nested if..um it was more of a pseudo code..shouldn't have used the C# tag but then didn't know what else to use

Answer (score 0):

Apart from avoiding keywords, the only thing I can immediately see wrong with getting var assigned as myString's value is that your example literal isn't double-quoted. (I'm assuming you're not having issues with myString getting destroyed before you access it given you're saying that it's not returning the same value as var. If you're trying to access myString from outside the if that you initialise it in, you need to initialise it less locally than you currently are)

String literals need to be inside double-quotes to function correctly, so check if var is correctly assigned to 1 in your base program. If that's not it, and you've got correct scope on myString, you're going to need to post your actual code rather than pseudocode, because it's hard to catch your error here otherwise.